# Pristine/valid not updating in textbox

Tags: angular

Can anyone explain why the valid or pristine check wouldn't update? Entering a name changes the model value (model.firstname), but if I make the name 1 character long in my test case, it does not display an error, when I expected it to violate the min length requirement of 4.

```
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" required [(ngModel)]="user.firstname" 
  name="firstname" #namecontrol="ngModel">
<div [hidden]="namecontrol.valid || namecontrol.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
  Name is required
</div>
```

**My component**

```
 @Input() user:GcUser;
 editUserForm:FormGroup;

......

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.editUserForm = new FormGroup({
    'firstname': new FormControl(this.user.firstname, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4)
    ])
  });

}
```

**After changing based on the suggestion below to implement Reactive Forms**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You should change the [`updateOn`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions#updateOn) setting of the `FormControl` to update on 'change':</strike>

```
this.editUserForm = new FormGroup({
  firstname: new FormControl(this.user.firstname, {
     validators: [
       Validators.required,
       Validators.minLength(4)
     ],
     updateOn: 'change'
   })     
});
```

Of course that shouldn't help, because the default value is 'change'. Your issue is that you are using so called reactive forms (FormGroup/FormControl) in combination with Template driven forms (NgModel). To get the result that you want, you have to update your template to this:

```
<form [formGroup]="editUserForm">
  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" required>
  <div [hidden]="editUserForm.controls.firstname.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
    Name is required
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Rilcon42 You are right, I should have read better :) I've updated my answer

Comment: I tested your suggestion, and I added the error to my post. I have no clue why Im getting an error related to ngModel however.... that is nowhere in the components code

Comment: @Rilcon42 somewhere inside your form there is a `ngModel`. Do you still have this `#namecontrol="ngModel"`, or are there any other inputs inside the form?

Comment: That was my bad. when I re-launched the server it corrected itself, but now I get a reference to undefined (error above)

Comment: @Rilcon42 that's my bad, it should be `editUserForm.controls.firstname.valid`. Untested code :)

Comment: You are welcome! Happy coding :D be sure to read the reactive forms cookbook on angular.io